# test setup error in django. self is not passing.

Tags: python, django, testing, error-handling

I am testing a class in django and then I have got this error, not recognizing self. It raised an error that says XYZClassTest has no attribute 'email'.  What am I missing?

```
def XYZClassTest(TestCase):
   def setup(self):
       self.email = 'xyz@test.com'
       ...

   def test_values(self):
       print 'the email addr is ', self.email
       ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it *doesn't* have an `email` attribute; the `setup()` method does. You need to use `setUp()` instead of `setup()`. Case matters!

Read more [in the unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp).

Comment: Great! Please select my answer to close up this question.

Comment: Another simple question again. How can I close it up?

Comment: There should be a check mark to the left of my answer, right below the rating arrows. You just have to click that.